# connecting to a pptpd server using openvpn client

Tags: debian, openvpn, pptpd

I have a pptpd server on debian.
Is it possible to use openvpn client instead of pptp client to connecting to a pptpd server?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am informed it is not possible to connect to a PPTP server via a OpenVPN (SSL-VPN) client since the two protocols are entirely different.

Comment: My university have a vpn server i can connect to it with pptp client and openvpn client. How it can possible?

Comment: I assume they simply installed both, an OpenVPN as well as a PPTP server. They have a similar setup in my university.

Comment: The both services on a single port(1723). Is it possible?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Simply set different ports for both services and you should be fine. You can provide your clients/colleagues the client.ovpn file to allow them connecting to your server easily. I wrote a brief tutorial on how to configure an OpenVPN server and how to configure clients about a year ago: http://www.betamaster.us/blog/?p=444 It's for Ubuntu but should be similar for Debian.

Comment: I can connect to my university vpn with pptp client and openvpn client on same port. So i think it's possible to connect to a pptp/openvpn server using openvpn/pptp client.

Comment: Perhaps the OpenVPN server is set to UDP instead of TCP/IP. It's impossible for TCP/IP to bind two applications to the same port as far as I know.